# How to ignore case when assigning values to the class members

Tags: c#, serialization

Am having a below class

```
public Class Properties{
   public Person PersonDetails{get; set;}
}

public Class Person{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
}
```

I have saved the class in `xml` format.

Now I have modified the `Person` class `Lastname` as `LastName`.

So, am getting the problem when deserializing the saved class and assigning the value

```
Properties personProperties = new Properties();

personProperties.PersonDetails = PersonDetails;

PersonDetails contains the de-serialized information.
```

The `LastName` value is not stored on deserializing.

Is there any `xml` attribute to specify in the `LastName` property.

Need to ignore the case, on assigning the value in below line

```
personProperties.PersonDetails = PersonDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a loot at XML **attributes** for providing alias during XML serialization/deserialization.

Try following in your class.

```
public class Person{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastname")]
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Reference: [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes)